# Sending cropped image data through Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which contains two input type="file" fields and a submit button. One of the file fields will be user cropped, the other one will not. The cropping plugin I am using is cropbox. I have the basic user interface set up, but I don't understand how I can send the form data with the cropped image and uncropped image through Ajax to PHP. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn5fjsdw/) of what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<form class="image_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="cropimage">
  <input type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#cropimage").on('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });
      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 600,
          height: 400
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {
          submission(JSON.stringify(results));
        });
      });
      $('body').append($img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

function submission(get_data) {
  $(".image_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(get_data);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
  });

}
```

Once the user has uploaded an image, it'll check if the submit button has been pressed to send through Ajax. How can I send the cropped image through Ajax and not the original image?

Comment: There are several projects named "cropbox". You should probably provide a link to the one you're using, and possibly read the associated documentation.

Comment: @jcaron I am using this one https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox

Answer (score 1):

When using `FormData` you can append `Blob` with resized image directly to it.

CropBox plugin has `getBlob` method which can be used to get blob with cropped image. All you need is to append blob to your formData:

```
formData.append('croppedFile', imageBlob)
// or if you want to add filename
formData.append('croppedFile', imageBlob, 'cropped.jpg')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox#methods

Comment: Does Blob work on certain browsers or all HTML5 Browsers?

Comment: `Blob` is supported in all modern browsers, and IE version 10 or above. About `getBlob` method in CropBox plugin - It also can be implemented, in all modern browsers(right way to do it, is - to use `canvas.toBlob`, but it needs a polyfill for some browsers - I have used https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob. About CropBox - it looks like they are using the same approach as in mentioned polyfill - so it should work in all modern browsers).